# Slc cracks in new floor want to us asca main floor

Tags: cement, cracks

I poured slc 13 days later it got hairline cracks in it. My question is will it stop cracking I want to stain and seal it as a main floor.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's word soup. Also, expand your abbreviations for those of us unfamiliar with them.

Answer (score 1):

SLC is not meant to be the final finished floor. You will have continuing issues. You may want to consider having the floor epoxy coated like some garage floors are done.